# CakePHP Set Value in Before Filter

Tags: php, cakephp

i am using Cakephp1.3  and i am trying to set value in app_controller.php under beforeFilter Function here is my Code.

```
function beforeFilter() {

  $sess =  $this->Session->read();

  if(isset($sess['Auth']['User'])) {
  $checkLogin = 1; 
  }
  else { $checkLogin=0; }

  $this->set('checkLogin',$checkLogin);

  //$this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';        
  $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');        
  $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index');
  $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');        
 }
```

Now i want to Access Checklogin value in user_controller.php

i tried this

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
     echo $checkLogin; exit;
    $this->Auth->allow(array('users' => 'login'));
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';

     }
```

i got this error

> undefined variable::checklogin()

Please tell me solution for this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `checkLogin` unless you make it a global variable.Check [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use an instance variable not a local. Instead of

```
$checkLogin
```

use

```
$this->checkLogin
```

in both controllers and it will work.

Example:

```
class AbstractUser{
    function __construct(){
        $this->instanceVar = true;
        $localVar = true;
    }
}


class User extends AbstractUser{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function useVariables(){
        var_dump(isset($this->instanceVar));  # returns true
        var_dump(isset($localVar));           # returns false
    }
}

$user = new User;

$user->useVariables();
```

**EDIT**

Updated the example to resemble more your use case.

Comment: Global is not the right answer here. In your AppController you set `$this->checkLogin = 1` and in your UserController you can use it with `$this->checkLogin` after the `parent::beforeFilter()` call. The mentioned variable scope documentation does not provide you any help in this case, you need to read about [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)